# How to modify specific ListView items to post back to db - MVVM

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I have `ListView` with `Button` showing status A(Absent), P(Present) and L(Late) for each item. On `Button` click status `Text` getting changed P to A, A to L.

When changing status of any item, I have to change *AttendanceId, AttendanceTypeStatusCD, AttendanceTypeStatusId* fields for for the same record. This I have to do for multiple records. I need to update my `ListView`'s source `StudentList` according to action performed and post modified data to db.

```
<ListView x:Name="list1"  ItemsSource="{Binding StudentList}">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout>
                <Image Source="other.png" />
                <Label Text="{Binding StudentName}" />
                <Button x:Name="mybtn"                                
                    BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference list1}, Path=BindingContext}" 
                    Command="{Binding BtnTextCommand}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference mybtn}}"                       
                    Text="{Binding AttendanceTypeStatusId, Converter={x:StaticResource IDToStringConverter}}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This is my model class

```
    public class Student
    {
        public int? StudentId { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public int? AttendanceTypeStatusId { get; set; }
        public string ClassLevelCd { get; set; }
        public int? StudentDailyAttendanceId { get; set; }
        public int? AbsentReasonId { get; set; }
        public string AttendanceTypeStatusCD { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LoggedInUser { get; set; }
        public string ImageValue { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the method in ViewModel in to change specific item text

```
public void SetBtnText(object sender)
{
    var view = sender as Xamarin.Forms.Button;
    if (view.Text == "P")
    {
        view.Text = "A";               
        AbsentReasonId = "3001";
        AttendanceTypeStatusCD= "Absent";
        AttendanceTypeStatusId = "3002";
    }
    else if (view.Text == "A")
    {
        view.Text = "L";
        AbsentReasonId= "2001";
        AttendanceTypeStatusCD = "Late";
        AttendanceTypeStatusId = "2002";
    }
    else
    {
        view.Text = "P";
        AbsentReasonId = "4001";
        AttendanceTypeStatusCD = "Present";
        AttendanceTypeStatusId = "4002";
    }
}
//Above used properties
private string _absentReasonId;
public string AbsentReasonId
{
    get { return _absentReasonId; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _absentReasonId, value); }
}


private string _attendanceTypeStatusCD;

public string AttendanceTypeStatusCD
{
    get { return _attendanceTypeStatusCD; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _attendanceTypeStatusCD, value); }
}

private int _attendanceTypeStatusId;
public int AttendanceTypeStatusId
{
    get{return _attendanceTypeStatusId;}
    set { SetProperty(ref _attendanceTypeStatusId, value); }
}
```

The above process is **not working**, SutdentList source not getting changed, How can I do that using MVVM?

Student list screenshot

[image]

Comment: you do not modify the view directly.  You modify the model's properties, which will cause the View to update, but only if your model implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: I am using Prism, I think it not need INotifyPropertyChanged, it has built in(not sure). Whenever I am changing above values like AttendanceTypeStatusId, It getting changed for all List not for specific records. How can  I fix it. Thank you.

Comment: you appear to be modifying class level properties, not the properties of individual records in StudentList

Comment: Oh! If you have any link or suggest pl give me so that I can fix it. Thank you.